# How to trigger message send of Fastapi websocket outside of Fastapi app

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, redis, fastapi

I have a `WebSocket` connection manager like this :

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connections  = {}
 
    async def connect(self, user_id: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.connections[user_id] = websocket

    async def disconnect(self, user_id):
        websocket: WebSocket = self.connections[user_id]
        await websocket.close()
        del self.connections[user_id]

    async def send_messages(self, user_ids, message):
        for user_id in user_ids:
            websocket: WebSocket = self.connections[user_id]
            await websocket.send_json(message
```

and a WebSocket route :

```
@router.websocket("/ws/{token}")
async def ws(websocket: WebSocket, token: str, redis :Annotated [Redis, Depends(get_redis)]):
    user_id = redis.get(token)
    if user_id:
        redis.expire(user_id)
    else:
        raise redis_error
    
    try:
        manager.connect(user_id, WebSocket)
    except WebSocketException:
        manager.disconnect(user_id)
```

I want to store the user connections and when a `Redis pubsub message` comes through, process the message and then send a `WebSocket message` to some users. the module that processes the message is not part of the `Fastapi` app.

i tried to implement this inside of the `Fastapi` app by implementing `threading` and `asyncio` but these to interupted the `Fastapi` app itself.

how can I trigger the send message of `WebSocket objects` outside of the `Fastapi application`?

**What I've tried:**

```
redis = Redis(redis_host, redis_port)
pubsub = redis.pubsub()
pubsub.subscribe("channel_signal")

@router.websocket("/ws/{token}")
async def ws(websocket: WebSocket, token: str):
    message = await  
    pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
    if message is not None:
         # do something
    try:
        manager.connect(user_id, WebSocket)
    except WebSocketException:
        manager.disconnect(user_id)
```

but I get pubsub error from redis and it says that i haven't subscribed yet unless i do it like this:

```
@router.websocket("/ws/{token}")
async def ws(websocket: WebSocket, token: str):
    redis = Redis(redis_host, redis_port)
    pubsub = redis.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe("channel_signal")

    message = await  
    pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
    if message is not None:
        # do something
    try:
        manager.connect(user_id, WebSocket)
    except WebSocketException:
        manager.disconnect(user_id)
```

but this creates a redis connection for every user that connects to the websocket, is there anyway to globally define a redis connection for all users?

**Update 1:**

with VonC answer i wrote this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketException
from v1.endpoints.user.auth import router as auth_router
from v1.endpoints.signals import router as signals_router
from configs.connection_config import redis_host, redis_port
import redis.asyncio as aioredis
import threading
import asyncio
import uuid

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(auth_router, prefix="/users/auth", tags = ["auth"])
app.include_router(signals_router, prefix="/signals", tags = ["signals"])



class ConnectionManager:
    last_message = ""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connections  = {}
 
    async def connect(self, user_id: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.connections[user_id] = websocket

    async def disconnect(self, user_id):
        websocket: WebSocket = self.connections[user_id]
        await websocket.close()
        del self.connections[user_id]

    async def send_messages(self, user_ids, message):
        for user_id in user_ids:
            websocket: WebSocket = self.connections[user_id]
            await websocket.send_json(message)

manager = ConnectionManager()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def ws(websocket: WebSocket):
    try:
        await manager.connect(str(uuid.uuid4()), websocket)
    except WebSocketException:
        await manager.disconnect(str(uuid.uuid4()))

redis_client = None
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event_connect_redis():
    global redis_client
    redis_client = aioredis.Redis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port)

def listen_to_redis():
    pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe("channel_signal")
    while True:
        message = pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
        if message:
            print(message["data"])

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event_listen_redis():
    # Starting the separate thread to listen to Redis Pub/Sub messages
    threading.Thread(target=listen_to_redis, daemon=True).start()
```

since `aioredis` is deprecated im using the `redispy` version of `aioredis`.

I have a problem with this part:

```
while True:
   message = pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
   if message:
       print("hi")
```

`if message` always comes true and at continuously prints `hi` so any event would be triggered indefinitely.

**Update 2:**

Although I could'nt test the answer fully due to another issue with `fastapi` (which I will open a new thread for and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77149945/cannot-manage-multiple-users-websocket-connection-in-fastapi) here) update added in the answer achieved defining a global redis connection for all users and listening to it separately from fastapi life cycle, I had to use the actual `aioredis` library instead of the `redispy` version.

Comment: Your other application can listen to the same redis queue as your FastAPI application would, and when a message has been read, process it and either re-add it to the queue (with recipients added) or a separate queue?

Comment: my main problem is how to make fastapi listen to redis and then get the websocket objects to send the message to users

Comment: It'll follow [the same pattern as seen in the reference documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) - you make a request to your websocket endpoint, and then `await redis.xread` or something similar to get a message on a redis stream; then emit that to the relevant connected clients.

Comment: This could work by doesnt every websocket connection mean also there is redis connection ? is there anyway to define a redis connection globally for all websocket connections?

Comment: I have edited [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77144944/6309) to address your edit.

Comment: @VonC thanks for your answer! i updated the question because I faced another issue related to this question but your answer helped a lot

Comment: You are most welcome. Hopefully, I might be able to help in your other question too, and have posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150073/6309) there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement a global [Redis](https://redis.io/) connection and use it across different WebSocket connections in your [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) application, you should consider creating a *shared* Redis client that is initiated when your FastAPI app starts.

And to process Redis pubsub messages independently of FastAPI request-response life cycle, you can create a separate thread or process to listen to Redis pubsub messages and trigger the WebSocket messages accordingly.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from aioredis import create_redis_pool
import threading
import json
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

# Connection manager class definition (place your existing implementation here)
class ConnectionManager:
    # same as your code

# Global variables
manager = ConnectionManager()
redis_client = None

# Step 0: WebSocket Connection Request (Client)
@app.websocket("/ws/{user_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, user_id: str):
    await manager.connect(user_id, websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            # (handle received messages if necessary)
    except:
        await manager.disconnect(user_id)

# Step 1: Global Redis Client and Connection Manager
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    global redis_client
    redis_client = await create_redis_pool("redis://localhost:6379")

# Step 2: Separate Thread for Redis Pub/Sub Listener
def listen_to_redis():
    pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe("channel_signal")
    
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        if message['type'] == 'message':
            data = json.loads(message['data'])
            process_redis_message(data)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event_2():
    # Starting the separate thread to listen to Redis Pub/Sub messages
    threading.Thread(target=listen_to_redis, daemon=True).start()

# Step 4: Processing Redis Messages
def process_redis_message(data):
    user_ids = data.get('user_ids')
    content = data.get('content')
    if user_ids and content:
        send_websocket_messages(user_ids, content)

# Step 5: Sending WebSocket Messages
def send_websocket_messages(user_ids, content):
    for user_id in user_ids:
        websocket = manager.connections.get(user_id)
        if websocket:
            asyncio.run(websocket.send_text(content))
```

The way messages are sent to WebSocket connections from outside the FastAPI application is through Redis pubsub messages, following this workflow:

```
  External System           FastAPI App                       Redis Server
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |--------(1) Initialize ----------->|
        |                         |        Redis Client               |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |-------(2) Start Thread ---------->|
        |                         |       (listen_to_redis)           |
        |                         |                                   |
 (0) WebSocket                    |                                   |
 Connection --------------------> |                                   |
 Request (Client)                 |                                   |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |                                   |
        |----(3) Publish Msg----->|                                   |
        |  to Redis channel       |                                   |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |<-------(4) Redis Listener --------|
        |                         |      (receive & process msg)      |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |                                   |
        |                         |------(5) WebSocket Msg ---------->|
        |                         |       (send to users)             |
        |                         |                                   |
```

0. **WebSocket Connection Request (Client)**: Clients initiate WebSocket connections by sending a request to the WebSocket endpoint in your FastAPI application.

   Inside this endpoint, you use the connection manager to manage (store, retrieve, delete) these WebSocket connections.
   That step sets up the necessary infrastructure to manage WebSocket connections, which are used in step 5 to send messages to the connected clients.

   ```py
   from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket

   app = FastAPI()
   manager = ConnectionManager()  # Make sure to define ConnectionManager class

   @app.websocket("/ws/{token}")
   async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, token: str):
       user_id = await redis.get(token)
       if user_id is None:
           # Handle unauthorized access
           return

       await manager.connect(user_id.decode('utf-8'), websocket)  # Assuming user_id is stored as bytes in Redis
       try:
           while True:
               data = await websocket.receive_text()
               # Handle incoming WebSocket messages (if any)
       except:
           await manager.disconnect(user_id.decode('utf-8'))
   ```
1. **Global Redis Client and Connection Manager**: A global Redis client and WebSocket connection manager are established at the start of your FastAPI application. The connection manager keeps track of all active WebSocket connections.

   ```py
   from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, Depends
   from aioredis import create_redis_pool

   app = FastAPI()
   redis_client = None
   manager = ConnectionManager()

   class ConnectionManager:
       # (same as your existing implementation)
   ```

   Initialize the Redis client when your FastAPI app starts:

   ```py
   @app.on_event("startup")
   async def startup_event():
       global redis
       redis_client = await create_redis_pool("redis://localhost:6379")  # replace with your Redis server details
   ```

   (I use [`aioredis`](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a Redis client designed to work with Python's asyncio. Adjust the Redis client instantiation and usage according to the Redis client library you are using.)
2. **Separate Thread for Redis Pub/Sub Listener**: A separate thread is initiated to listen to Redis pubsub messages continuously.

   That thread operates independently of the FastAPI application, in the sense that it is not bound to any specific route or endpoint in your FastAPI app.
   It can receive and process messages even if they are published from outside the FastAPI application - potentially from another service or application that has access to the same Redis instance.

   ```py
   import threading

   def listen_to_redis():
       global redis
       pubsub = redis.pubsub()
       pubsub.subscribe("channel_signal")

       while True:
           message = pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
           if message:
               user_ids = process_redis_message(message)  # Step 4 function called here
               send_websocket_messages(user_ids, message)  # Step 5 function called here

   # Starting the separate thread to listen to Redis Pub/Sub messages
   threading.Thread(target=listen_to_redis, daemon=True).start()
   ```
3. **Publishing Messages to Redis from Outside the FastAPI App:** Any external system or service that wants to send a message to the WebSocket connections managed by your FastAPI application can do so by publishing a message to the Redis channel that your FastAPI application is subscribed to ("`channel_signal`" in this case).

   That external system/service does not need to interact with your FastAPI application directly; it only needs to be able to publish messages to the Redis channel.

   Something like:

   ```py
   import redis

   redis_host = "your_redis_server_host"  # Replace with your Redis server host
   redis_port = "your_redis_server_port"  # Replace with your Redis server port

   client = redis.Redis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port)

   channel_name = "channel_signal"
   message = {"user_ids": ["123", "456"], "content": "Hello, World!"}

   client.publish(channel_name, json.dumps(message))
   ```
4. **Processing Redis Messages:** When a message is published to the Redis channel, the separate thread running the `listen_to_redis` function picks up the message.

   Inside this function, you would implement the logic to process the Redis message and identify the `user_ids` of the WebSocket connections to which the message should be sent.

   ```py
   def process_redis_message(data):
       user_ids = data.get('user_ids')
       content = data.get('content')
       if user_ids and content:
           send_websocket_messages(user_ids, content)
   ```
5. **Sending WebSocket Messages:** Once the `user_ids` are identified, the `listen_to_redis` function calls the `send_messages` method of the connection manager to send the message to the appropriate WebSocket connections.

   That method iterates over the identified `user_ids` and sends the message to each corresponding WebSocket connection.

   ```py
   def send_websocket_messages(user_ids, content):
       for user_id in user_ids:
           websocket = manager.connections.get(user_id)
           if websocket:
               asyncio.run(websocket.send_text(content))
   ```

So, to trigger a WebSocket message send from outside the FastAPI application:

- An external system/service publishes a message to the Redis channel.
- The `listen_to_redis` function, running in a separate thread, receives and processes this message.
- The processed message is then sent to the appropriate WebSocket connections through the connection manager's `send_messages` method.

That mechanism should allow messages to be sent to WebSocket connections from outside the FastAPI application through the intermediary of Redis pub/sub.

---

> I have a problem with this part:
>
> ```
> while True:
>   message = pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
>   if message:
>       print("hi")
> ```
>
> `if message` always comes true and at continuously prints `hi` so any event would be triggered indefinitely.

The `listen_to_redis` function, specifically, `pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)` seems to always be returning a non-`None` value, even when no message is available, causing the `if message:` statement to evaluate to `True`.

Your function `listen_to_redis` seems to be synchronous, while the rest of your FastAPI application is asynchronous.
And the `get_message()` (message loop) function is non-blocking, meaning that it will immediately return `None` if no message is available, leading to high CPU usage in a `while True` loop.

For asynchronous operations like handling WebSocket and Redis pub/sub, it is better to utilize [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). You can listen to the Redis channel asynchronously like this:

```py
from asyncio import run

async def listen_to_redis():
    pubsub = await redis_client.subscribe("channel_signal")
    channel = pubsub[0]

    while await channel.wait_message():
        message = await channel.get(encoding="utf-8")
        print("Message:", message)
```

And the startup event to listen to Redis can be made asynchronous as well, ensuring better compatibility with FastAPI.

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event_listen_redis():
    asyncio.create_task(listen_to_redis())
```

The goal is for your Redis pub/sub should operate asynchronously and fit better within the FastAPI ecosystem. Note that this will require using an asynchronous Redis client compatible with FastAPI's async capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Probably another option would be to move the redis listener into a separate process and add route /new_redis_message to FastAPI. /new_redis_message should be able to send a message to the WebSocket of any client.

A separate question arises: how will all this work if we have several FastAPI instances (several pods). Where the summary relationship "pod fast-api" <=> "websocket client XXX" will be stored