# Cannot manage multiple users websocket connection in fastapi

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I want to store and manage user **websocket** connections in a **dictionary** so I can create custom events for each user.

**Here's a really simple implementation of what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
app = FastAPI()
con = {}
@app.websocket("/ws/{id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, id: str):
    try:
        print("connect", id)
        await websocket.accept()
        con[id] = websocket
        print("check", con.keys())
        for uid in con:
            print(uid)
            await con[uid].send_text("hello")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**and here's the log :**

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [26605] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [26610]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
connect 1
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 48346) - "WebSocket /ws/1" [accepted]
check dict_keys(['1'])
1
INFO:     connection open
connect 2
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 48354) - "WebSocket /ws/2" [accepted]
check dict_keys(['1', '2'])
1
Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close'.
INFO:     connection open
```

When I connect to websocket with client `1` everything works as expected and I get the message `hello`.

**client 1 log:**

```
CONNECTING: WS://LOCALHOST:8000/WS/1

CONNECTION READY

hello

CONNECTION CLOSED!
```

but when the seconds client connects to `websocket` it returns an exception in the server:

```
Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close'.
```

**and client 2 doesn't get any message:**

```
CONNECTING: WS://LOCALHOST:8000/WS/1

CONNECTION READY

CONNECTION CLOSED!
```

**I run the app like this:**

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [FastAPI WebSocket route](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) does not seem to have an event loop to continuously handle incoming or outgoing messages for each connected client.
Meaning: as soon as the function `websocket_endpoint` finishes executing, the WebSocket connection is automatically closed by FastAPI, leading to the unexpected [ASGI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/) message error.

Putting the `connections` dictionary *outside* the function scope would allow multiple WebSocket connections to be stored and accessed across different function invocations.

You would need a `while True:` loop to make sure the WebSocket connection remains open, allowing for continuous message sending and receiving.

And adding some error handling is never a bad idea: that would help to handle client disconnections gracefully via [`WebSocketDisconnect`](https://www.starlette.io/websockets/#receiving-data). This way, the connection can be removed from the `connections` dictionary when a client disconnects.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from typing import Dict

app = FastAPI()
connections: Dict[str, WebSocket] = {}

@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: str):
    await websocket.accept()
    connections[client_id] = websocket

    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            # Do something with received data (optional)
            
            for uid, ws in connections.items():
                await ws.send_text(f"Client {client_id} says: {data}")

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        del connections[client_id]
```

As an example, the code sends incoming messages from any client to all connected clients. You can customize this as needed for your use case.

New workflow:

```
   +---------------------+
   |  websocket_endpoint |
   +-------+-------------+
           |
           |
   +-------v-----------------+
   |await websocket.accept() |
   +-------+-----------------+
           |
           |
   +-------v----------------------------+
   | connections[client_id] = websocket |
   +-------+----------------------------+
           |
           |
           |<-------------------------------------------+
           |                                            |
   +-------v----------+                        +--------+------------+
   |   while True:    |                        | WebSocketDisconnect |
   +-------+----------+                        +--------+------------+
           |                                            |
           |                                            |
   +-------v-------------------------------+   +--------v-------------------+
   | data = await websocket.receive_text() |<--| del connections[client_id] |
   +-------+-------------------------------+   +----------------------------+
           |
           |
   +-------v-----------------------------+
   | for uid, ws in connections.items(): |
   +-------+-----------------------------+
           |
           |
   +-------v--------------+          +--------------------+
   | await ws.send_text() |---...--->|     while True:    |
   +-------+--------------+          +--------------------+
```